# How to get an attribute from an XMLReader

Tags: java, android, xmlreader, tag-soup

I have some HTML that I'm converting to a `Spanned` using `Html.fromHtml(...)`, and I have a custom tag that I'm using in it:

```
<customtag id="1234">
```

So I've implemented a `TagHandler` to handle this custom tag, like so:

```
public void handleTag( boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader ) {

    if ( tag.equalsIgnoreCase( "customtag" ) ) {

        String id = xmlReader.getProperty( "id" ).toString();
    }
}
```

In this case I get a SAX exception, as I believe the "id" field is actually an attribute, not a property. However, there isn't a `getAttribute()` method for `XMLReader`. So my question is, how do I get the value of the "id" field using this `XMLReader`? Thanks.

Comment: Where is `TagHandler`?  The usual way to do SAX2 is to use `ContentHandler`s, no?

Comment: `TagHandler` is used when converting HTML text to Spannable text via `Html.fromHtml(String, ImageGetter, TagHandler)`. It's for handling unknown tags (tags not recognized by TagSoup).

Comment: I see. I just tagged the question with TagSoup so those familiar with this parser can find the question.  I do know that in the regular SAX2 parser in the standard Java libraries you just setup ContentHandlers, not TagHandlers, and the startElement callback has the attributes already present.

Comment: I had the same problem and when I looked at the Android source code, I saw that the attributes are intentionally not passed. So I replace tags with attributes with other tags which have a specific name. Like <customtag1234> in your case.

Comment: @rekire No, I didn't. I ended up doing what vorrtex suggested.

Comment: I found a solution with reflecting the xmlReader. Inside is a theElement were I found the attributes. I can post the code next week.

Comment: @rekire Sure, feel free. I'll try it out once you post it and accept it if it works.

Comment: Does anyone have experience with replacements like https://github.com/NightWhistler/HtmlSpanner or https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is my code to get the private attributes of the `xmlReader` by reflection:

```
Field elementField = xmlReader.getClass().getDeclaredField("theNewElement");
elementField.setAccessible(true);
Object element = elementField.get(xmlReader);
Field attsField = element.getClass().getDeclaredField("theAtts");
attsField.setAccessible(true);
Object atts = attsField.get(element);
Field dataField = atts.getClass().getDeclaredField("data");
dataField.setAccessible(true);
String[] data = (String[])dataField.get(atts);
Field lengthField = atts.getClass().getDeclaredField("length");
lengthField.setAccessible(true);
int len = (Integer)lengthField.get(atts);

String myAttributeA = null;
String myAttributeB = null;

for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if("attrA".equals(data[i * 5 + 1])) {
        myAttributeA = data[i * 5 + 4];
    } else if("attrB".equals(data[i * 5 + 1])) {
        myAttributeB = data[i * 5 + 4];
    }
}
```

Note you could put the values into a map but for my usage that's too much overhead.

Comment: Hmmm, this keeps throwing java.lang.NoSuchFieldException - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @slott there are three possibilities: The field does not exists anymore (might be an incompatible version); in general you are accessing a private field and you forgot to call `setAccessible(true)` or it is part of a base class in the last case you need to inspect its superclass.

Comment: I got it working - trick was not to call as the first thing inside the  handleTag method :) Thanx for help though - always helps when someone pushes you through the rough patches of life...

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to use `XmlReader` provided by `TagHandler` and get access to tag attribute values without reflection, but that method is even less straightforward than reflection. The trick is to replace `ContentHandler` used by `XmlReader` with custom object. Replacing `ContentHandler` can only be done in the call to `handleTag()`. That presents a problem getting attribute values for the first tag, which can be solved by adding a custom tag at the start of html.

```
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.Locator;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;

public class HtmlParser implements Html.TagHandler, ContentHandler
{
    public interface TagHandler
    {
        boolean handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, Attributes attributes);
    }

    public static Spanned buildSpannedText(String html, TagHandler handler)
    {
        // add a tag at the start that is not handled by default,
        // allowing custom tag handler to replace xmlReader contentHandler
        return Html.fromHtml("<inject/>" + html, null, new HtmlParser(handler));
    }

    public static String getValue(Attributes attributes, String name)
    {
        for (int i = 0, n = attributes.getLength(); i < n; i++)
        {
            if (name.equals(attributes.getLocalName(i)))
                return attributes.getValue(i);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private final TagHandler handler;
    private ContentHandler wrapped;
    private Editable text;
    private ArrayDeque<Boolean> tagStatus = new ArrayDeque<>();

    private HtmlParser(TagHandler handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader)
    {
        if (wrapped == null)
        {
            // record result object
            text = output;

            // record current content handler
            wrapped = xmlReader.getContentHandler();

            // replace content handler with our own that forwards to calls to original when needed
            xmlReader.setContentHandler(this);

            // handle endElement() callback for <inject/> tag
            tagStatus.addLast(Boolean.FALSE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
            throws SAXException
    {
        boolean isHandled = handler.handleTag(true, localName, text, attributes);
        tagStatus.addLast(isHandled);
        if (!isHandled)
            wrapped.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException
    {
        if (!tagStatus.removeLast())
            wrapped.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
        handler.handleTag(false, localName, text, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDocumentLocator(Locator locator)
    {
        wrapped.setDocumentLocator(locator);
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException
    {
        wrapped.startDocument();
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException
    {
        wrapped.endDocument();
    }

    @Override
    public void startPrefixMapping(String prefix, String uri) throws SAXException
    {
        wrapped.startPrefixMapping(prefix, uri);
    }

    @Override
    public void endPrefixMapping(String prefix) throws SAXException
    {
        wrapped.endPrefixMapping(prefix);
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException
    {
        wrapped.characters(ch, start, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void ignorableWhitespace(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException
    {
        wrapped.ignorableWhitespace(ch, start, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void processingInstruction(String target, String data) throws SAXException
    {
        wrapped.processingInstruction(target, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void skippedEntity(String name) throws SAXException
    {
        wrapped.skippedEntity(name);
    }
}
```

With this class reading attributes is easy:

```
    HtmlParser.buildSpannedText("<x id=1 value=a>test<x id=2 value=b>", new HtmlParser.TagHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, Attributes attributes)
        {
            if (opening && tag.equals("x"))
            {
                String id = HtmlParser.getValue(attributes, "id");
                String value = HtmlParser.getValue(attributes, "value");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This approach has the advantage that it allows to disable processing of some tags while using default processing for others, e.g. you can make sure that `ImageSpan` objects are not created:

```
    Spanned result = HtmlParser.buildSpannedText("<b><img src=nothing>test</b><img src=zilch>",
            new HtmlParser.TagHandler()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, Attributes attributes)
                {
                    // return true here to indicate that this tag was handled and
                    // should not be processed further
                    return tag.equals("img");
                }
            });
```

Comment: I just tried this and the handler part works really good, however the built-in parser is somehow messed up, `<tag attr="a & b">text</tag>` is parsed as `attributes = {attr="a", _="_", b="b"}`. Using `&amp;` is similarly bad.

Comment: @TWiStErRob for me `String testStr = "<tag attr=\"a & b\">text</tag>";` gets parsed correctly. I get the problem you described by parsing `String testStr = "<tag attr=a & b>text</tag>";`, which is not really a valid html.

Comment: Hmm, you're using hard-coded Java, I read the value from resources: `<string name="..."><![CDATA[ ... <tag...> ... ]]></string>`. Maybe something got lost in transmission while the framework read the XML. I worked around it by using Java identifiers (e.g. enum constant name) instead of plain text in attributes, so they're only a "word" long.

Answer (score 9):

Based on the answer by rekire I made this slightly more robust solution that will handle any tag.

```
private TagHandler tagHandler = new TagHandler() {
    final HashMap<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();

    private void processAttributes(final XMLReader xmlReader) {
        try {
            Field elementField = xmlReader.getClass().getDeclaredField("theNewElement");
            elementField.setAccessible(true);
            Object element = elementField.get(xmlReader);
            Field attsField = element.getClass().getDeclaredField("theAtts");
            attsField.setAccessible(true);
            Object atts = attsField.get(element);
            Field dataField = atts.getClass().getDeclaredField("data");
            dataField.setAccessible(true);
            String[] data = (String[])dataField.get(atts);
            Field lengthField = atts.getClass().getDeclaredField("length");
            lengthField.setAccessible(true);
            int len = (Integer)lengthField.get(atts);

            /**
             * MSH: Look for supported attributes and add to hash map.
             * This is as tight as things can get :)
             * The data index is "just" where the keys and values are stored. 
             */
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                attributes.put(data[i * 5 + 1], data[i * 5 + 4]);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception: " + e);
        }
    }
...
```

And inside handleTag do:

```
    @Override
    public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader) {

        processAttributes(xmlReader);
...
```

And then the attributes will be accessible as so:

attributes.get("my attribute name");

Answer (score 1):

There's an alternative to the other solutions, that doesn't allow you to use custom tags, but has the same effect:

```
<string name="foobar">blah <annotation customTag="1234">inside blah</annotation> more blah</string>
```

Then read it like this:

```
CharSequence annotatedText = context.getText(R.string.foobar);
// wrap, because getText returns a SpannedString, which is not mutable
CharSequence processedText = replaceCustomTags(new SpannableStringBuilder(annotatedText));

public static <T extends Spannable> T replaceCustomTags(T text) {
    Annotation[] annotations = text.getSpans(0, text.length(), Annotation.class);
    for (Annotation a : annotations) {
        String attrName = a.getKey();
        if ("customTag".equals(attrName)) {
            String attrValue = a.getValue();
            int contentStart = text.getSpanStart(a);
            int contentEnd = text.getSpanEnd(a);
            int contentFlags = text.getSpanFlags(a);
            Object newFormat1 = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
            Object newFormat2 = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
            text.setSpan(newFormat1, contentStart, contentEnd, contentFlags);
            text.setSpan(newFormat2, contentStart, contentEnd, contentFlags);
            text.removeSpan(a);
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

Depending on what you wanted to do with your custom tags, the above may help you. If you just want to read them, you don't need a `SpannableStringBuilder`, just cast `getText` to `Spanned` interface to investigate.

**Note that `Annotation` representing `<annotation foo="bar">...</annotation>` is an Android built-in since API level 1! It's one of those hidden gems again.** The It has the limitation of one attribute per `<annotation>` tag, but nothing prevents you from nesting multiple annotations to achieve multiple attributes:

```
<string name="gold_admin_user"><annotation user="admin"><annotation rank="gold">$$username$$</annotation></annotation></string>
```

If you use the `Editable` interface instead of `Spannable` you can also modify the content around each annotation. For example changing the above code:

```
String attrValue = a.getValue();
text.insert(text.getSpanStart(a), attrValue);
text.insert(text.getSpanStart(a) + attrValue.length(), " ");
int contentStart = text.getSpanStart(a);
```

will result as if you had this in the XML:

```
blah <b><font color="#ff0000">1234 inside blah</font></b> more blah
```

One caveat to look out for is when you make modifications that affect the length of the text, the spans move around. Make sure you read the span start/end indices at the correct times, best if you inline them to the method calls.

`Editable` also allows you to do simple search and replace substitution:

```
index = TextUtils.indexOf(text, needle); // for example $$username$$ above
text.replace(index, index + needle.length(), replacement);
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is just one attribute the suggestion by vorrtex is actually pretty solid. To give you an example of just how simple it would be to handle have a look here:

```
<xml>Click on <user1>Johnni<user1> or <user2>Jenny<user2> to see...</<xml>
```

And in your custom TagHandler you don't use equals but indexOf

```
final static String USER = "user";
if(tag.indexOf(USER) == 0) {
    // Extract tag postfix.
    String postfix = tag.substring(USER.length());
    Log.d(TAG, "postfix: " + postfix);
}
```

And you can then pass the postfix value in your onClick view parameter as a tag to keep it generic.